# What is the phonetical difference between phrases like "зачем пришел" and "за чем пришел"?

Tags: фонетика

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19839) about the meaning of "**научись**," and it turned out that in the movie in which I heard this, it was not "**научись**," but "**на, учись**." This was a real trap! The Russian phonetics is so tricky!

Kind users of this forum explained to me that the particle **на** in "**на, учись**" is somewhat more stressed than the prefix  **на** in "**научись**" is, and I got curious whether this is a general principle to distinguish between prefixes and separate words and whether I should always stress words that could be taken for a prefix.

My question is this: What is the difference in pronunciation between:

(1) "**Зачем пришел?**" ("Why did you come?") and "**за чем пришел?**" ("What thing did you come to take?").

(2) "**Выхóдите гулять?**" ("Are you going out to walk now?") and "**Вы ходите гулять?**" ("Do you regularly go to walk?").

(3) "**Он невежливый**" ("He is impolite") and ""**он не вежливый**" ("He is not polite").

(4) "**Давайте порублю**" ("Let me cut") and "**давайте по рублю**" ("Give me one rouble each").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no phonetical difference, those phrases are pronounced exactly the same way. Whether one should write "не" together or separately, for instance, is quite often a source for confusion of Russian pupils exactly because of this.

As of "на, учись" - well, the comma exists for a reason, in this case there's indeed a gap between pronouncing "на" and "учись".

Comment: Ohh.. But do you agree with the others that "**научись**" is pronounced differently from "**на, учись**"?

Comment: Ah, I see, you reflected this in an update to your post, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mitsuko nice examples by the way - it looks like your understanding of Russian language is on a very high level!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind compliment. I am indeed among the best students (judging by grades), but still nowhere near you, native speakers. You are like gods to me.

Comment: oh it's not a valid comparison - native speakers does not count after all )

Answer (score 2):

Only the *second* example can show phonetic difference which reveals itself in interrogative *tone rising* on one or another word. In **Выходите гулять?** (in the context '*Is it for a walk* that you are going out for now?') the word **гулять** is emphasized with tone rising, as opposed to the other question, where the word **ходите** is emphasized. However, another context is possible for the first question (emphasis on **выходите**) where it sounds the same as the second one: asking someone to hurry up with their going out for a walk.

Comment: Isn't there a difference in the meaning between "*Вы ходите гулять(!)?*" and "*Вы ходите(!) гулять?*" either?

Comment: There _is_ some. The first version contains a _guess_ **гулять** (You often go out - is it for a walk?). The second one is a neutral question (Do you do such a thing as going for a walk?)

Comment: Ohhh... This is so tricky! I was sure that the neutral question requires the neutral Intonation, in which none of the words is stressed. I was sure that the question "*Вы ходите(!) гулять?*," with "ходите" stressed, means something like, "How do you get to the place where you walk - by walking or by public transport?"

Comment: The context of getting to workplace needs different words: _вы ходите (на работу) **пешком**_. _Гулять_ is just walking for pleasure.

Comment: Aha I see. Our languages then have something in common - the meaning is often determined by subtleties of the context.

Comment: BTW, гулять is even never combined with a direction or a target place.

Comment: @Alex_ander how about "пойдем гулять в парк"? I believe "парк" is a target place here. I guess you meant that the act of "гулять" can't have a destination, but if you "идешь гулять" then "идешь" can have a destination (at which you'll "гулять"). Does it make sense? I can't find a way to express it better...

Comment: Парк is the target place of **пойдём** here, _not_ of the verb_ гулять_, which is about the action that will just take place in the park (мы пойдём в парк - туда - и будем _там_ гулять = ходить по неопределённой траектории - когда придём).

Answer (score 2):

### #1.

> "Зачем пришел?" ("Why did you come?")
> "За чем пришел?" ("What thing did you come to take?")

Both sound the same, but if Russian ear hears this phrase with 100% Russian brain thinks that it is [зачем пришел].

---

### #2.

> "Выхóдите гулять?" ("Are you going out to walk now?")
> "Вы ходите гулять?" ("Do you regularly go to walk?").

Both sound the same, but first sound unnatural to Russian ear.
In real life it will be like this

> "Гулять выхóдите?" ("Are you going out to walk now?")

---

### #3.

> "Он невежливый" ("He is impolite")
> "Он не вежливый" ("He is not polite").

Both sound the same, but said aloud it does not have difference in meaning.
For Russian ear it is 100% first variant [невежливый].
For Russian ear the second varian usually goes with [not this, but this]

> "Он невежливый." ("He is impolite")
> "Он не вежливый, а мошенник" ("He is not polite, but a cheater").

---

### #4.

> "Давайте порублю" ("Let me cut")
> "Давайте по рублю" ("Give me one rouble each").

Both sound the same, but context is too different to mix it.
For Russian ear it is 100% the first [порублю].

For the second it is sound unnatural.
In real life they will say like this.

> "Сдавайте по рублю" ("Give me one rouble each").

[Давайте по рублю] is also possible, but it is about robbery.

> [Давайте скинемся по рублю] ("Let's make a mutual fund by investing 1 ruble from each of us").
>
> [Давайте скинемся, а то порублю] ("Let's make a mutual fund, otherwise I will cut you all").

---

### Bonus track

- [научись] must be pronounced [науч'ись] - one stress
- [на, учись] must be pronounced [н'а] [pause] [уч'ись]- two stresses

[на] here is a short form for [возьми]
[на, учись] = [возьми и учись]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation :)